# Can you install docker on Debian 6?

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, docker

This is weird legacy setup but I have a server running Debian 9 as host and Debian 6 as guest using virtualbox or vmware. Is it possible to install docker in the guest Debian 6 VM? I couldn't find the minimum OS requirements for Docker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I couldn't find the minimum OS requirements for Docker.

It's a strange you couldn't find it
https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/debian/

https://www.google.com/search?q=docker+debian+requirements

Comment: I am running docker on Debian 9 currently. That mean's docker still supports the previous installations. What if I install using older packages?

Comment: Of course with older release you can

Comment: There's a hard requirement related to kernel features: kernel 3.10. Debian 6 comes with kernel 2.6.32...